# Divinity: Original Sin Enhanced Edition multiplayer

Tags: divinity-original-sin

Is gameplay any different in Divinity:  Original Sin Enhanced Edition multiplayer than in the single player game?

I was thinking of playing the game with a friend when I first got it, but I have been playing solo for a while and I cannot see how this would work in reality.  There is so much to read, choices to make, places to go, etc.  Playing with someone would require constant   Reading things, wanting to do different things, etc.  Does the gameplay change at all, or do you have to just have really good communication with your partner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gameplay is actually very well suited to coop.

- You can solve the puzzles using several characters with communication instead of having to coordinate your 2-4 characters yourself
- In town, you can do what you want. What I did in my coop playthorugh was to spend time in town reading, while my mate went around trying to steal stuff. Give yourselves 5-15 minutes after you completed the usual quest dialogues and buying/selling before going back out
- Dialogues often give both players the chance to chime in with their own opinion allowing you both to roleplay. There is no lead character as there is in many other multiplayer capable RPGs.
- There is is actually a mechanic to resolve conflicts between players. In many dialogues where both main characters are asked for their opinion, you can disagree, e.g. the first such example would be the shell at the beginning of the game where one could argue to keep it and the other to throw it into the ocean. If you disagree, you can then try to persuade your mate to see it your way using the speech skills (charm etc.), this then may end up in the persuasion minigame (the rock-paper-scissors thing). Eventually the action chosen by the winning player will be done.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. My co-op buddy through both Divinity games would often run around stealing everything while I did the talking and reading

Comment: I guess I will just have to try it.  I have a feeling one of us would get frustrated with the pace or choices of the other...